# Can't update Azure Function in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have developed an Azure function in a .Csx file  that calls a C# library.

**Creation of the Function App in Azure is fine**.

**First deployment to Azure is Ok**.

**Any update to the function that makes a change to the called Dll works fine on the local emulator.**

But as soon I deploy a new version (using Web deploy, or a custom deploy script using  Zip + REST API) of the Function App to Azure, I get a message like :

```
2017-02-10T16:54:29.160 Exception while executing function: Functions.MailSenderFunction. mscorlib: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. f-MailSenderFunction__-1032464143: 
Method not found: 'Void MyCompany.MailSenderFunctionLib.MailSenderFunctionProcessor.Run(MyCompany.MyProject.Common.Models.Mail, MyCompany.MailSenderFunctionLib.LogHandler)'.
```

Even if I delete the function before deployment using Portal, Http Rest API, it does not help.

**I need to recreate a brand new function App resource in order to have my new version to work**

With no change to code, If a create a brand new empty Function App and deploy the Function App to Azure, then I get a nice working Azure function in Azure.

**But I can't redeploy to same Azure Function App.**

I ve been searching for a week.
I am afraid it is an Azure bug.

Has anybody an idea ?

Comment: Does restarting the function app help? Function App Settings -> App Service Settings -> Restart

Comment: Actually, it got working after I left my work, some few hours after. I just pressed on Run in the Develop tab to see a message saying my function was executed. Then I produced another version of my dll + call from the csx, redeployed. Same error msg as above. Then I pressed on Restart, and sent a msg in the service bus queue that is the trigger, and I got the same error msg about the not found method... I'll have a look tomorrow. Looking at the dll in the bin/directory of my function, and decompiling, i just observe, it 's the latest. Not first time I ve got a cache/delay feeling

Comment: This is is a limitation that will be fixed soon, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/pull/1169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using azure functions with dlls for a while now and got around the issue with using Team Foundation Service Release builds.

I structured my release builds into 3 steps

**Step 01.** stop the azure function app using <s>power shell</s> azure powershell.

**Step 02.** commit your changes to azure function internal git repo

**Step 03.** start the azure function app using <s>powershell</s> azure powershell.

*you can get the powershell cmd for doing this from the portal itself.*

Portal -> your app -> resource explorer -> click the "Go" link in the blade which opens a new tab -> there should be a powershell tab which has all the related powershell commands.

Hope this helps

Comment: My deployment process is not Git, but REST API, but it works for me. I gave a try with the portal instead of Powershell, it didn't work, but using Azure Powershell commands as you advised, it works. Thanks Frictionlesspulley

Comment: sorry i too meant azure powershell cli.. updating the answer